# updating listviews android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I am very new to android! I've created a vertical linearlayout with two listviews inside my listfragment and I just want every of this listviews show simple array of strings which I can update during runtime. I it seems very difficult for me to realize how to do this. Here are my files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/trainslist"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/timelist"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" >
        </ListView>         
</LinearLayout>
```

This is a fragment XML file, and here is a fragment file:

```
public class ToFragment extends ListFragment {   
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String[] countries = {
                "Japan",
                "USA"
        };
       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(inflater.getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, countries);             
        setListAdapter(adapter1);
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

Look, here I try to make one of listviews show what I need and it works. But I don't understand how to thange it's content during runtime (not from onCreateView?) from Activity. It's also unclear for me what is android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1? Why, when I write it, android sends my array to the first listview, not second?

The second issue is I can't change second listview content even in this way, even not during runtime! Please help me deal with this! I really find it so difficult...